# Custom 404 error page for controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have implemented codeigniters 404 override , it works fine for incorrect parameters but when you type in an incorrect controller it goes back to the default 404 page.  It is probably a simple solution but cannot seem to find the answer.

Comment: Try by creating custom core controller inside application/core as MY_Controller and extend all your controllers from it and put your 404 page method inside MY_Controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to set custom 404 over ride follow the [style guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

```
application > controllers > Error_404.php
```

Filename: Error_404.php

```
class Error_404 extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {

   }

}
```

Codeigniter error 404 over ride only works on the first level of controllers.

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error_404';
```

Not work

```
$route['404_override'] = 'pages/error_404';
```